# One ffmpeg instance/build is 3x slower than my other ffmpeg instance/build. Why?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 separate ffmpeg instances on my macOS machine (10.14.2 Mojave and Intel Core i5-8259U Quad-core CPU @ 2.30GHz, if that helps):

1 - Installed with brew (and linked with my local dylib's)

2 - A static build downloaded from [Zeranoe's ffmpeg builds](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Both are v4.1. But, when transcoding the same file (OGG -> MP3) with the same command options, with the same system load, and everything else being equal ... **instance #1 is roughly 3x faster than instance #2. I need to know why because I need to bundle a static ffmpeg build with my app, and it needs to perform optimally**. See command output below:

The faster instance of ffmpeg (Note the speed is 46.5x):

```
$ ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -i ~/Reiki2.ogg -vn -sn ~/Reiki2.mp3
size=   26290kB time=00:28:02.54 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=46.5x
```

The slower ffmpeg instance (Note the speed is 17.2x)

```
$ ./ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -i ~/Reiki2.ogg -vn -sn ./Reiki2.mp3
size=   26290kB time=00:28:02.54 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=17.2x
```

Why the huge difference in performance ???

If I figure this out, I can then build ffmpeg myself with optimized performance matching my faster installed ffmpeg (i.e. #1).

Is it how the two instances were configured prior to *make* ? Do you see any significant configuration options that are the reason for this huge difference in performance ?

I am dying to know this since my app depends on ffmpeg performance. I would really appreciate any insights. Thanks in advance !

**Instance #1 (faster)** was configured as follows:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)

configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1 --enable-shared
--enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables
--enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay 
--enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy
--enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 
--enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl 
--enable-videotoolbox

libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

**Instance #2 (slower)** was configured as follows:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)

configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 
--enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass
--enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame 
--enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb 
--enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine 
--enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora 
--enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack 
--enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 
--enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib 
--enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis 
--enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex 
--enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-appkit 
--enable-avfoundation --enable-coreimage --enable-audiotoolbox

libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

---

**------ UPDATE: ------**

1 - I tried building libmp3lame myself with --enable-nasm and then ffmpeg using that built lame. No difference noticed ... still slow.

2 - I ran the same transcoding tests on a much older Mac, and the results were nearly identical (scaled down because it's a slower computer).

**i.e. libmp3lame is definitely the problem !**

So, I have decided, for my app, that I will use a workaround - I will simply prefer transcoding to AAC instead of MP3. AAC transcoding is lightning fast on all my ffmpeg instances and my app supports AAC well. I will also continue to investigate the libmp3lame slowness problem, but for now, I am unblocked wrt my app.

Thanks to all for the help ! (Special thanks to @Gyan and @
llogan)

Comment: Can you give the full output of running the commands rather than the clipped output? There might be some hints in the debug text.

Comment: Done - Included full output in original post above.

Comment: Sorry, previous output post was not complete. Edited again with verbose output.

Comment: Odd. Everything looks identical and there are no meaningful differences. I was wondering if it could be CPU optimisation but cannot find any evidence of the encoder or decoder using SIMD.

Comment: Right, I also suspect that the installed instance was able to take advantage of knowing that it's not going to be ported to another machine so it could optimize for my hardware/software. And,  I also tried building on my own with "--enable-runtime-cpudetect", and that made no difference. It matched the slower ffmpeg's performance :( So, there must be some other optimization. But, there are SO MANY configure options, I looked at all mentions of "cpu"... nothing useful.

Comment: I have two other Mac's I could run the same tests on. Perhaps I should do this performance comparison on those machines too, and see if I can detect some sort of relation between processor cores and difference in performance between the 2 instances ? Maybe this difference will be more significant on a quad core machine (this one) than on an older dual core machine (assuming that the faster ffmpeg is taking advantage of better hardware).

Comment: Have you tried other encoders - `aac`? Also, video encoding?

Comment: @Gyan I'm so glad you mentioned that ! I just tried DSF > AIFF transcoding and the slower instance #2 was actually the faster instance this time ! 36x vs 28x.

So I guess it depends on the codecs being used. I got fixated on my OGG > MP3 because for my app, it is a more important use case than other conversions.

Haven't tried video transcoding because it is irrelevant to my app (audio player).

I guess I will need to do more testing with more codecs and see if I can find a configuration that works best for my most important use cases.

Comment: AIFF isn't very instructive, as default codec is uncompressed. Try AAC and video transcoding. The aim is to identify the issue; doesn't matter if you won't be actually doing video stuff.

Comment: Ok, tried video and aac. Video (avi > mp4, 104 mins duration): The "slower" instance was 3x faster than the "faster" one (28x vs 10x). And on mp3 > aac (98 mins duration), the "slower" instance was slightly faster than the "faster" one (108x vs 95x).

Comment: Right. So looks to be a libmp3lame issue. Compile LAME and ffmpeg yourself and check.

Comment: ... or a libvorbis issue (OGG), right ? Do we know if it's the OGG decoding or MP3 encoding that is causing the slowdown ? I guess, to be sure, I could try OGG to a different format and see if OGG (Vorbis) is the culprit.

Will try compiling lame/ffmpeg out again tomorrow and report back. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. Cheers !

Comment: The command is using the inbuilt decoder, so not libvorbis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87312/discussion-between-waldencalms-and-gyan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is likely a bug from LAME

[#491 lame 3.100 slower than 3.99.5](https://sourceforge.net/p/lame/bugs/491/)

I informed Zeranoe and johnvansickle.com about this. John said this will be fixed with his git release on 20 December. He said he compiled lame with `CFLAGS="-O3" CPPFLAGS="-DNDEBUG"` resulting in a 3x speedup.

### Be aware of nasm

Enabling nasm seems to make a significant difference for 3.100 compared to 3.99.5 in my lazy test on Arch Linux.

Both Zeranoe and John compile lame with `--enable-nasm`, so the slowness in their builds is due to the previously mentioned bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information and for doing the testing ! I will try this out and report back.

BTW, if possible, could you update your post with the command output from your test runs ? I'm curious about the details.

(Upvoted your answer but it won't show coz I'm a new user.)

Comment: I built libmp3lame myself, with --enable-nasm ... no difference observed :( However, I found a workaround (read updated original post). Thanks !

Comment: @waldenCalms I updated the answer. It's a bug.

Comment: Wow, thank you, Sir ! You are awesome :) Will look out for the fixed libmp3lame build and re-test with it !!! I will have to wait for Zeranoe because I'm on macOS, not Linux.

Comment: @waldenCalms I recommend continuing using AAC if it is acceptable for you. Generally, it's usually a little better quality per bitrate (depends on the encoder and settings of course). And if you're muxing into MP4 then AAC is better supported than MP3.

Comment: Yup, will use AAC for now. Thanks so much ! Upvoted and accepted your answer.